# Convert any R variable's value to string

Tags: r, object, tostring

Coming from Java/Scala, I have been trying to figure out how to convert any value to a string equivalent.

Essentially, I would like to take the output you see in the R REPL and use that as the string.

```
myFunc <- function(x) { x + 1}
myFunc
#function(x) { x + 1}
```

Other cases are like with `SparkR`:

```
sc
#Java ref type org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext id 0
```

I've tried using options like `toString()` and `as.character()`, but those both fail:

```
toString(myFunc)
#Error in paste(x, collapse = ", ") :
#  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

toString(sc)
#Error in as.vector(x, "character") :
#  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'
```

I can do a hack like this:

```
rawString <- function(obj) {
  tmp <- "/tmp/rawString.txt"
  if (file.exists(tmp)) file.remove(tmp)
  sink(tmp)
  print(obj)
  sink()
  dataString <- paste(readLines(tmp))
  if (file.exists(tmp)) file.remove(tmp)
  trimws(dataString)
}
function(obj) {
  tmp <- "/tmp/rawString.txt"
  if (file.exists(tmp)) file.remove(tmp)
  sink(tmp)
  print(obj)
  sink()
  dataString <- paste(readLines(tmp))
  if (file.exists(tmp)) file.remove(tmp)
  trimws(dataString)
}


rawString(sc)
#[1] "Java ref type org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext id 0"

rawString(myFunc)
#[1] "function(x) { x + 1}"
```

But, I would like to avoid writing to and reading from files *and* relying on `sink()`. Is there a way to get a string representation like the REPL prints out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `capture.output`. It's essentially your `rawString`, but built in.

```
capture.output(myFunc)
[1] "function(x) { x + 1}"
```

Unfortunately I can't speak for `sparkTable` as I don't have it.

You might also consider `?dput`, which is a good way to provide something for users to copy-paste into their consoles to recreate your variable, though doesn't convert to string (e.g. `dput(iris)` --> if I were to copy-paste this into my terminal I'd get exactly what you got).