# How to evaluate a variable and print as a string/character in R?

Tags: r, string, character, eval

I've tried finding this on SO without any luck:

How do I convert a closure object into a string in R?

I have a list of functions, like this:

```
functions = c(function(x) 2*x, function(x) sin(x*pi), function(x))
```

And, I iterate over them like `for (func in functions){...`, and I'd like to be able print the function expression as part of my plotting.

I've tried:

```
toString(eval(func))
as.character(eval(func))
```

What gives?

Related links:

- [How to evaluate a variable as an expression for axis label in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804590/how-to-evaluate-a-variable-as-an-expression-for-axis-label-in-r)
- [Evaluate expression given as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string)

Comment: Thank you @TigerhawkT3  for your edit

Comment: something like this: as.character(parse(text=func))

Comment: why can't I use `func` instead of `functions[2]`?

Comment: wanted to quickly show you something that works.

Comment: The closest I can get is this: `as.character(parse(text=as.list(func)))`

Comment: doesnt as.character(parse(text=func))  achieve what you want?

Comment: No, it throws an error: `Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'`

Comment: wah more complicated than i think  haha... check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421462/convert-any-r-variables-value-to-string someone also solved this using capture.output

Comment: temp <- lapply(functions, function(func) capture.output(func)); lapply(temp, class)

Comment: What are you trying to do with them? You can chuck them in a list, or wrap the expression in `quote` (or `expression`) for easy `eval` later, but the best approach depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no easy way to accomplish this.  Here is the best way I found:

`as.character(parse(text=as.list(func)))`

For a more general solution, you can capture the output, as @chinsoon said.